# Unable to import a local js file in react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Below code works — trying to import jquery file from node modules

```
Import $ from ‘jquery’;
```

Below code doesn’t work— I am trying to import the same jquery file from ‘clientapp/src/kendo’ folder

```
Import $ from ‘../kendo/jquery’;
```

Can you please suggest how to fix. Actually I have few licensed js library files, it errors when I try to import them from ‘clientapp/src/kendo’ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resolve.alias` in webpack to import the modules from a directory that has more levels up in the filesystem.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

As a good practise, you should not import files from node_modules, those are compiled in webpack, so you use the import `import $ from 'jquery'`